# AngularJs Timer Performance Issue

Tags: angularjs, performance, timer, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using angularJs v1.3.10, And I am making a large application having complex array, I am using ng-repeat on these datastructures.

Some part of pages also use timer, which changes the time per second so my data structure changes per second, so complete dom related to this array reloads. What should be the right process to implement timer in ng-repeat.

initially $apply cycles are around few hundred ms, but after few operations, it goes to few seconds.

what should i do, for page performance.(I am also adding classes dynamically inside ng-repeat).

Comment: How have you implemented timer using $interval?